# Java 8 Stream sorting List of String

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, java-stream

I am calling the sorted method on a stream. And the java doc says:

**"Sorted method returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream, sorted according to natural order."**

But when I run the code below:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("b");
list.add("a");
list.add("z");
list.add("p");
list.stream().sorted();
System.out.println(list);
```

I am getting output as

```
[b, a, z, p]
```

Why am I not getting the output of a natural sort?

Comment: sorted() returns a stream with the elements sorted, it doesn't sort your current stream.

Comment: @Snickers3192: you meant “it doesn’t sort the `List`” as there is no “current stream”. Naming things that wrong leads to exactly the confusion, the OP has shown.

Comment: @Holger Sorry yeah replace stream with list.

Answer (score 15):

Change this

```
list.stream().sorted();
System.out.println(list);
```

to something like

```
list.stream().sorted().forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Your method is println the `list` (not the sorted stream). Alternatively (or additionally), you could shorten your initialization routine and re-collect the `List` like

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("b","a","z","p"));
list = list.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(list);
```

Which outputs (as you probably expected)

```
[a, b, p, z]
```

Comment: I think you mean `forEachOrdered`, not `forEach`.

Comment: There is no reason to copy the result of `Arrays.asList` to an `ArrayList`; the method `Arrays.asList` returns a `List`. In either case, the list is mutable and doesn’t need a stream detour like `list = list.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());` a simple `list.sort(null);` will sort the list in-place.

Answer (score 8):

You should collect the result of the sorting and then assign it to your list.

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("b");
    list.add("a");
    list.add("z");
    list.add("p");
    list = list.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to have your sorted list.

Let's change this

```
list.stream().sorted();
```

to

```
list.sort((e1, e2) -> e1.compareTo(e2));
```

Hope this help!

Comment: unfortunately, this is not a acceptable answer. Because, the OP's way is indeed correct. You don't need to pass a custom comparator in order to get the natural ordering for a given stream of string objects. BTW; above 2 answers will point what has went wrong. Hope you could learn something from it :)

Comment: @Jude: do you know the difference between calling `list.stream().sorted()` and calling `list.sort(…)`? The custom comparator might be obsolete, still, this answer is correct.

Comment: @Holger hi, the 1st one will just sort the elements in natural order. *(using compareTo or obj.toString().compareTo() implementations)*. Ohh, man... It's a new default method added from Java 8 to List interface. Sorry, my bad. But, this answer, doesn't point out the fact that intermediate operations won't fire unless having a terminal operation.

Comment: @Jude: even with a terminal operation, stream operations do not modify the source list. Yes, this answer lacks explanations, but provides a straight-forward solution. Though, I’d prefer `list.sort(null)` or `list.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder())`…

Comment: @Holger yes. `Comparator.naturalOrder()` is to the point.

Answer (score 4):

Your stream has no terminal operator, and therefore is not processed. Terminal operators include but are not limited to: forEach, toArray, reduce, collect. Your code segment should be similar to

```
list.stream().sorted().forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I think you mean `forEachOrdered`, not `forEach`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Ah yes, thank you. I'll make sure to edit it.