# Using a lambda expression for a comparable

Tags: java, lambda, comparable

```java
import java.util.*;  
import java.io.*; 

class Simpson implements Comparable<Simpson> {
    String name;

    Simpson(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    ( simpson) -> {
        return this.name.compareTo(simpson.name);
    }
}

public class Main {

     public static void main(String... sortingWithList) {
        List<Simpson> simpsons = new ArrayList<>();
        simpsons.add(new Simpson("Homer "));
        simpsons.add(new Simpson("Marge "));
        simpsons.add(new Simpson("Bart "));
        simpsons.add(new Simpson("Lisa "));

        Collections.sort(simpsons);
        simpsons.stream().map(s -> s.name).forEach(System.out::print);
```

I want to use a lambda expression for a comparable, but I am getting an error.

Comment: Why did you want to implement lambda on a class?

Comment: Your code seems incomplete. I suggested an edit to format it properly. Please tell us which error you got ([edit] and post error Output as text). Do you just want to sort the names alphabetically?

Comment: There is a JEP draft: Concise Method Bodies. https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8209434 I don't know whether any progress has been made to integrating it yet. In the mean time, just use a standard public method.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead of `Collections.sort`:

```
simpsons.sort((s1, s2) -> s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2));
```

Comment: Is `sort` on collections persistent (does it modify them) or does it just return a sorted collection (immutable)? As learner I would ask

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you are implementing Comparable, which means it implements the compareTo method.

```
import java.util.*;  
import java.io.*; 

class Simpson implements Comparable<Simpson> {
    String name;

    Simpson(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    int compareTo(Simpson other){
        return this.name.compareTo(other.name);
    }
}

public class Main {

     public static void main(String... sortingWithList) {
        List<Simpson> simpsons = new ArrayList<>();
        simpsons.add(new Simpson("Homer "));
        simpsons.add(new Simpson("Marge "));
        simpsons.add(new Simpson("Bart "));
        simpsons.add(new Simpson("Lisa "));

        Collections.sort(simpsons);
        simpsons.stream().map(s -> s.name).forEach(System.out::print);

     }
```

}

Comment: Yes OP tried to implement, but apparently forgot the name, return type, visibility. May I remind you that neither the code of question, nor yours will run (syntax).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Java Doc for interface [`Comparable<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

It provides a method to compare this object against another object (passed in parameter `o`) of the same type (in your case: T is `Simpson`)

```
int compareTo(T o)
```

Also your `name` properties are **already comparable**, because of type `String`, which [implements this interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-) too. So you can simply delegate (as you already well did).

#### Supposed error

Please **correct the method signature**, it's currently incomplete and might be the cause of a compilation error:

> @Override ( simpson) -> {
> return this.name.compareTo(simpson.name);
> . }

#### Fix issues

Give the method the same *name* and *return type*  and *parameters* as prescribed by the interface:

```java
public int compareTo(Simpson o) {
    if (o == null || this.name == null) return -1; // could adjust to your needs to avoid NPE
    return this.name.compareTo( o.name );
}
```

Most important: since interfaces are to be called from outside, the implemented methods must be `public`!

#### Just lambda

Or just go by **streaming** with appropriate **lambda expression** as suggested in previous answer

```
simpsons.stream()
    .map(s -> s.name) // map serves like delegation to name
    .sorted((s1, s2) -> s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2)) // sort previous with current element, here: names alphabetically
    .forEach(System.out::print);
```

Difference when sorting in streams:

- use `sorted()`, not `sort()` like for collections
- you can specify a `Comparator` as *functional* or *lambda expression*
- you can also sort by **natural order** (as illustrated in following question)

There is yet another, simpler way to sort strings lexicographically:

[Java 8 Stream sorting List of String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39950785/java-8-stream-sorting-list-of-string)

#### Comparator and natural-order

You can also combine both:
(1) comparable interface, implemented by Simpson
(2) stream with functional, sorted by comparator or lambda expression (as suitable).

```java
simpsons.stream() 
   .sorted((s1, s2) -> s1.compareTo(s2)) // sort previous with current Simpson ! explicit comparator passed as lambda
   .forEach( s -> System.out.println(s.name) );  // print name of Simpson in new line
```

#### In the simple case, you don't need to

Or you can use *intelligent* sorting and **! implicitly** reuse the existing **natural order** by replacing with `.sorted()`.
Try also what happens out-of-the-box (without any compareTo ⁉️):

```java
class Simpson {
    String name;

    Simpson(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

}

// main omitted, just the usage example:
simpsons.stream().sorted().forEach(System.out::println );
```

Sorting naturally would fallback to use `toString` if otherwise not comparable. Same way printing uses `toString`.

Does it sort correctly and print appealing❔

Comment: I am new to lambda expression. As lambda expression is using functional interface, comparable is also a functional interface. So how can I use lambda expression over here. Like we can use for comparator interface.

Comment: @SonamBanerjee No problem, I recognized already. As soon as your `Simpson` claas is correctly _Comparable_ you can just use `sorted()` on streams of `Simpson` objects. Then they "follow" a _natural order_: means the **-able** interface is used as **-ator** functional by default. See [`Comparator` tutorial](https://www.javaguides.net/2020/04/java-8-stream-sorting-with-comparator.html)